# How to remove duplicates from a corpus using the tm package in R

Tags: r, tm

I am trying to remove duplicates from a corpus using the `tm` package in R. For example, to
remove ampersands, I use the following R statements:

```
removeAmp <- function(x) gsub("&amp\;", "", x)

myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeAmp)
```

I then try to remove duplicates using the following:

```
removeDup <- function(x) unique(x)

myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeDup)
```

I get the error message:

> Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default

I have also tried

```
removeDup <- function(x) as.list(unique(unlist(x)))
```

but still get an error. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. `tm_map(crude, unique)` or `tm_map(crude, removeDup)` works fine for me.

Comment: By the way, I use the following command to read in files from a directory to form the corpus: myCorpus <-Corpus(DirSource('C:/cygwin/home/neeph/Test/uk'), encoding="UTF-8", readerControl=list(reader=readPlain))

Answer (score 1):

Removing duplicated entries can be done with the following code.

First, convert the previously cleaned corpus back to a data frame.

```
df.tweets<-data.frame(text=unlist(sapply(tweet.corpus, `[`,"content")), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Second, remove duplicates entries in the data frame

```
tweets.out.unique <- unique(df.tweets)
```

Third, convert it back to the a corpus (if needed) (assuming that the dataframe has one colum)

```
tweet.corpus.clean <- Corpus(DataframeSource(tweets.out.unique[1]))
```

I don't know if this is more elegant, but quite easy!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
clean.corpus <- function(corpus) {
      #remove "mc.cores=1" for windows! (Only necessary for Macintosh)
      removeURL <- function(x) gsub("http[[:alnum:]]*", "", x)
      myStopwords <- c(stopwords(use.stopwords), "twitter", "tweets","tweet","tweeting", "retweet", "followme", "account", "available", "via")
      myStopwords <- c(myStopwords, "melinafollowme", "voten", "samier", "zsm", "hpa", "geraus", "vote", "gevotet", "dagibee", "berlin")
      myStopwords <- c(myStopwords, "mal","dass", "für", "votesami", "votedagi", "vorhersage", "\u2728\u2728\u2728\u2728\u2728", "\u2728\u2728\u2728")
     cleaned.corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace, lazy=TRUE)
     cleaned.corpus <- tm_map(cleaned.corpus, content_transformer(tolower), mc.cores=1)
     cleaned.corpus <- tm_map(cleaned.corpus, content_transformer(function(x) iconv(x, to='UTF-8-MAC', sub='byte')), lazy=TRUE)
     cleaned.corpus <- tm_map(cleaned.corpus, removePunctuation, lazy=TRUE)
     cleaned.corpus <- tm_map(cleaned.corpus, removeNumbers, lazy=TRUE) 
     cleaned.corpus <- tm_map(cleaned.corpus, removeURL)
     cleaned.corpus <- tm_map(cleaned.corpus, function(x) removeWords(x, myStopwords), mc.cores=1);

     cleaned.corpus <- tm_map(cleaned.corpus,          
     function(x)removeWords(x,stopwords(use.stopwords)), mc.cores=1)

     removeDup <- function(x) unique(x)
     cleaned.corpus <- tm_map(cleaned.corpus, removeDup, mc.cores=1)

     cleaned.corpus <- tm_map(cleaned.corpus, PlainTextDocument)
     return (cleaned.corpus)
 }
```